# Python requests or urllib read timeout, URL encoding issue?

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to download a file from within Python, I've tried urllib and requests and both give me a timeout error. The file is at: [http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Incêndios%20Rurais%20-%20Histórico%20do%20Dia%2029SET.pdf](http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Inc%C3%AAndios%20Rurais%20-%20Hist%C3%B3rico%20do%20Dia%2029SET.pdf)

Using requests:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Incêndios%20Rurais%20-%20Histórico%20do%20Dia%2029SET.pdf',timeout=60.0)
```

Using urllib:

```
urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Incêndios%20Rurais%20-%20Histórico%20do%20Dia%2029SET.pdf','the.pdf')
```

I've tried different URLs, such as:

- [http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Incêndios Rurais - Histórico do Dia 29SET.pdf](http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Inc%C3%AAndios%20Rurais%20-%20Hist%C3%B3rico%20do%20Dia%2029SET.pdf)
- http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Inc%C3%AAndios%20Rurais%20-%20Hist%C3%B3rico%20do%20Dia%2029SET.pdf
- [http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Incêndios%20Rurais%20-%20Histórico%20do%20Dia%2029SET.pdf](http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Inc%C3%AAndios%20Rurais%20-%20Hist%C3%B3rico%20do%20Dia%2029SET.pdf)

And, I can download it using the browser and also with cURL using the following syntax:

```
curl http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Inc%C3%AAndios%20Rurais%20-%20Hist%C3%B3rico%20do%20Dia%2029SET.pdf
```

So I'm suspecting it's an encoding issue, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the server is responding differently depending on the client User-Agent. If you specify a custom `User-Agent` header the server responds with a PDF:

```
import requests
import shutil

url = 'http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Inc%C3%AAndios%20Rurais%20-%20Hist%C3%B3rico%20do%20Dia%2028SET.pdf'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'curl'}  # wink-wink
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open('result.pdf', 'wb') as output:
        response.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, output)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://www.prociv.pt/cnos/HAI/Setembro/Inc%C3%AAndios%20Rurais%20-%20Hist%C3%B3rico%20do%20Dia%2028SET.pdf'
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'curl'}  # wink-wink
>>> response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
>>> response.headers['content-type']
'application/pdf'
>>> response.headers['content-length']
'466191'
>>> response.raw.read(100)
'%PDF-1.5\r\n%\xb5\xb5\xb5\xb5\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(pt-PT) /StructTreeRoot 37 0 R/MarkInfo<</'
```

My guess is that someone abused a Python script once to download too many files from that server and you are being tar-pitted based on the User-Agent header alone.

Comment: Thank you! So simple, it hurts. I'll accept the answer as soon as possible.